# what is mysql date_format() equivalent in Presto or Postgres?

Tags: mysql, postgresql

From datetime `2018-12-12 10:10:10` to get only year-month I would usually do this in MySQL8.0

`date_format('2018-12-12 10:10:10', '%Y-%m')`

which outputs `2018-12`

How can I do this in Presto or Postgres?

I can do it with

`concat(cast(year('2018-12-12 10:10:10') as varchar),'-',cast(month('2018-12-12 10:10:10') as varchar)) as year_month`

but seems very cumbersome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Postgres, we can use `TO_CHAR` here:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR('2018-12-12 10:10:10'::timestamp, 'YYYY-MM') AS dt;
-- outputs 2018-12
```

Answer (score 0):

In presto

`date_format(date, '%Y-%m') as year_month`

seems to work.